# Out of bound String length()

Tags: java

There is an Alphabet object of letters and if an **int** passed into the parameter of the method **wrapObject** is out of bound, the method should wrap it back accordingly. If an object is "ABC" and the passed value is 5, so it should wrap back to the letter **C** I did here smth but my problem is what if the passed **int i** is much bigger- such as 1000 or negative number- than the length of an object.

```
Alphabet anyWord;
public int wrapInt(int i)
    {
        if (i > anyWord.length())
            return (i-alphabet.length());
        else 
            return i;
}
```

Comment: You're looking for the modulo (`%`) operator. Given an integer `i` and some maximum value `max`, the expression `i % max` will give you the remainder of `i / max`.

Comment: Use modulus instead of substracting it from length ,  i%alphabet.length()

Comment: I did the modulo operator, but what if the number is negative such as (-100%alphabet.length()) would still give the negative number ??

Comment: @jordan negatives are a whole different issue that you weren't originally asking about, but I see that you've edited your question to include it.

Comment: I understood for the postive numbers, but for the negative numbers: if there are 95 characters and a passed value is -5, so it should return 89. For the negative numbers, the method should calculate backwards. That's my problem for now.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
 return Math.abs(i) % alphabet.length();
```

Comment: That will make sure the index is within `alphabet`, but that's not really how negative indexing works.

Comment: I understood for the postive numbers, but for the negative numbers: if there are 95 characters and a passed value is -5, so it should return 89. For the negative numbers, the method should calculate backwards. That's my problem for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 Alphabet anyWord;

public int wrapInt(int i)
    {
        if (i > anyWord.length())
            return (i%alphabet.length());
        else 
            return i;
```

}